# How to use Conditional Formatting to Highlight Duplicate Values in Excel using EPPLUS

Tags: .net, epplus

I am trying to figure out how to highlight duplicate values in a given column using Conditional Formatting using EPPLUS excel library. In the list of validation types available, I cannot see Duplicate Value related type.
The idea here is that a column has several values but some of those are duplicated. So I wanted to have a formatting applied similar to the manual steps i.e. select the column (or range in question), go to Conditional Formatting - Highlight Cell Rules - Duplicate Values. Then basically any duplicates to be assigned a light red fill color. Alternatively, if I can possibly use a new Rule Type with formula similar =COUNTIF($B3:$B$3, $B3)>1 which can be applied to the whole range. But how to add new Rule Type as Conditional formatting using EPPLUS? Any suggestions, ideas welcome. I haven't posted code as I haven't got around making anything that captures the logic.

Answer (score 0):

after some trials and errors, managed to get this to work. sample code below hoping this can help someone looking for same info.

```
'Enable Automatic Calc mode on the excel workbook  
  p.Workbook.CalcMode = ExcelCalcMode.Automatic
 
 
 'Add Conditional formatting for the given range
 Dim cfRange As ExcelAddress = New ExcelAddress("B3:B" & ValToRow.ToString)
                Dim cfRule = ws.ConditionalFormatting.AddDuplicateValues(cfRange)
                cfRule.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid

                cfRule.StopIfTrue = False

                cfRule.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F8696B") 'red color
                
               'The Pattern Type and color can be set or ignored as it may affect readability of cell values. 
               ' Uncomment to change and use as desired
                'cfRule.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.LightHorizontal
               'cfRule.Style.Fill.PatternColor.Color = Color.WhiteSmoke
                
                'Add this line after above code.
                ws.calculate()
```